# Why Jesus said that the God abandoned Him?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, christology, gospel-of-luke, hypostatic-union

This is one of the most common questions of someone who starts reading the Bible. I found a lot of explanations, however, none of them is really creating a reasonable answer for why Jesus said that. Also if Jesus knows that He has been sent to Earth to die on The Cross to save all mankind, why is He sad in that garden when he begs His Father to remove this duty from Him: "Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me; yet not my will, but yours be done." - Luke 22:42.

I know He said that the Father's will should be done, not His will, however, he said to His Apostoles countless times that "The Son of Man will be given to the sinful men to be crucified". (Not an actual quote, just my translation to English from my language). Now, don't think I accuse Jesus of unfaithfulness or I deny His Divinity. I'm orthodox so I believe that God is the Father; God is the Son; God is the Holy Spirit.

All the explanations I found on this question revolve around the idea that His Human Nature was fighting with His Divine Nature. The part of Him that was God was saying: "Father, forgive them for they don't know what they are doing", the human part of Him screamed in pain to God that abandoned Him. The God Part from Him wanted to complete His ministry of salvation and to be crucified, the part that is human of Him was scared and asked to give up. However, I don't find this explanation of the 2 Natures: "The Divine Nature and The Human Nature" in Christ that were fighting each other.

I expect answers from the Holy Trinity perspective.

Comment: No one who believes and teaches the hypostatic union (that Jesus has two natures, divine and human) should ever say that those two natures are fighting with each other. That is directly contradicted by the [Chalcedonian Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition)! "acknowledged in Two Natures unconfusedly, unchangeably, indivisibly, inseparably"

Comment: You've already received one answer by a non-Trinitarian/non-Chalcedonian. It would help if you could please [edit] this to clarify whose answers you want, and whether you want an answer by traditional Trinitarian and Chalcedonian theology, or an answer by some other more minority group.

Comment: I said that I'm an orthodox and I believe in the Holy Trinity. I edited it to make the thread clear about the answer I expect

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Jesus did not intend by His utterance "My God, My God, why have you forsaken me" to communicate that God had forsaken Him. Indeed, as comments above have pointed out, that would be an heretical reading (to trinitarians).

Rather, He was quoting [Psalm 22](http://web.mit.edu/jywang/www/cef/Bible/NIV/NIV_Bible/PS+22.html), which begins with the same phrase. The purpose here was to call this psalm to mind, since it is a Messianic psalm which prophesies the crucifixion. Read further down into this psalm

> 1 My God, my God, why have you forsaken me? Why are you so far from saving me, so far from the words of my groaning?
> ...
> 7 All who see me mock me; they hurl insults, shaking their heads:
> 8 "He trusts in the LORD; let the LORD rescue him. Let him deliver him, since he delights in him." [Recall the Jews saying of Christ "He saved others, let him save Himself"]
> ...
> 10 From birth I was cast upon you; from my mother's womb you have been my God.
> 11 Do not be far from me, for trouble is near and there is no one to help.
> 12 Many bulls surround me; strong bulls of Bashan encircle me.
> 13 Roaring lions tearing their prey open their mouths wide against me.
> ...
> 16 Dogs have surrounded me; a band of evil men has encircled me **they have pierced my hands and my feet.**
> 17 I can count all my bones; people stare and gloat over me.
> 18 **They divide my garments among them and cast lots for my clothing.** [emphases mine]

And, the missionary work to follow the crucifixion and resurrection is also prophesized here

> 22 I will declare your name to my brothers; in the congregation I will praise you.
> 23 You who fear the LORD, praise him! All you descendants of Jacob, honor him! Revere him, all you descendants of Israel!
> 24 For he has not despised or disdained the suffering of the afflicted one; he has not hidden his face from him but has listened to his cry for help.
> 25 From you [that is, Israel] comes the theme of my praise in the great assembly; before those who fear you will I fulfill my vows.
> 26 The poor will eat and be satisfied; they who seek the LORD will praise him-- may your hearts live forever!
> 27 **All the ends of the earth** will remember and turn to the LORD, and **all the families of the nations will bow down before him**,
> 28 for dominion belongs to the LORD and he rules over the nations.
> 29 All the rich of the earth will feast and worship; all who go down to the dust will kneel before him-- those who cannot keep themselves alive.
> 30 Posterity will serve him; future generations will be told about the Lord.
> 31 They will proclaim his righteousness to a people yet unborn-- for he has done it. [emphases again mine]

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the Trinity and this is my understanding. Jesus was being expressive so that we can understand what was going on within Him and with the Father on the other side. If He didn't express that, we would not be knowing.

Let's take the case of Abraham sacrificing his son Isaac. God stopped him at the end and provided a ram instead (cf. Gen 22:12-13). Doesn't God knew beforehand that Abraham will obey Him?  Of Course He knew before the foundations of the earth. God withheld Abraham from sacrificing his son but He didn't withheld His own Son (Jesus Christ) for the sake of humans. Therefore now we can say to God what Gen 22:12 says to Abraham — “ For now I know that You love me LORD because You have not withheld Your son, Your only Son for me.”

In Gen 6:6, `So the LORD was sorry that He had made mankind on the earth and He was grieved in His heart.` Surely God knew the outcome before He made the man, yet He expressed it so that we can understand it grieves God when people sin and destroy themselves thereafter.

When Jesus Christ said `“Father, if You are willing, remove this cup from Me; yet not My will, but Yours be done.”` - Luke 22:42. Jesus was being expressive about what He was feeling because He is 100% human and He feels all the emotions and pains that we can. Imagine a hypothetical scenario where God has not expressed His feelings in the Bible, we don't understand the heart of God in the first place. Knowingly or unknowingly we know much about God and we can reason and justify the things about God and we can have a relationship with Him because He expressed Himself in the Bible wherever deemed necessary. In the verse `Yet not My will, but Yours be done`, how many instances have we not used this in church and as well as privately.

The prophecies relating to the suffering of Jesus Christ at the cross were written in Psalm 22 which were fulfilled.`My God, My God, why have You forsaken Me?`- Matthew 27:46. The Father (who is Holy and sinless) and Jesus Christ (who was carrying quintillions of all human sins at that point in time) cannot be joined together. `For what do righteousness and lawlessness share together, or what does light have in common with darkness?` - 2 Cor. 6:14. Therefore he was forsaken on our behalf. Whatever Jesus Christ has endured for our sins, we don't have to as a believer, that includes the abandonment / forsaking.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. *Doesn't God knew (sic) beforehand that Abraham will obey Him?* but then, *NOW I know that You love me*. Which means He didn't before - hence the test!

Comment: @steveowen Faith without works is dead - James 2:26 .Abraham displayed his faith by works.Now is used so that  Abraham as well as others can able to understand and relate as that's how humans communicate.At that point in time (Now), the message is clear to Abraham that God acknowledged that Abraham reveres God through the display of faith by works.

Answer (score 0):

God the Father did not forsake or abandon His only begotten Son on that cross. Jesus is quoting Psalm 22 where David was being hunted down by King Saul and he was describing his own feelings of forsakenness.

At vs11-13, "Be not far from me, for trouble is near; For there is none to help. vs12, Many bulls have surrounded me; strong bulls of Bashan have encircled me. Vs13, They open wide their mouth at me, as a raving and roaring lion."

When you read on the following is what David says at verses 23 and 24. "You who fear the Lord, praise Him; All you descendants of Jacob, glorify Him, And stand in awe of Him, all you descendants of Israel.

Vs24, For He has not despised or abhorred the affliction of the afflicted; Neither has He hidden His face from him; But when he cried to Him for help, He heard." I'm sure everyone of us at times felt we were forsaken or abandoned by God due to circumstances that seemed hopeless.

Jesus was not forsaken on that cross either, even though He knew that He would be forsaken by His closest friends. John 16:32, "Behold, an hour is coming, and has already come, for you to be scattered, each to his own home, and to leave Me alone; and yet I am not alone, because the Father is with Me. Also, the Father was in/with Him on that cross reconciling the world to Himself, not counting their trespasses against them, and He has committed to us the word of reconciliation. 2 Corinthians 5:19.

Comment: It’s no good saying scripture is wrong or misunderstood without explanation. *Jesus was not forsaken on that cross*, you say. Why wasn’t he then, when he suggested was?

Comment: @steveowen Well steve, if you would have taken your time and read what I wrote there would have been no need to ask this question. What's does my very last paragraph say? At John 13;32 Jesus knew in advance that His friends would forsake Him. He also says in the same verse, "and yet, I AM NOT ALONE. Why? Because the Father is WITH ME. With: accompanied by (another person or thing). Then there is 2 Corinthians 5:19, "namely, that God was IN Me reconciling the world to Himself." This is Sunday School stuff steve! Take your time and read with understanding and logic.

Comment: Yes I get all that but you haven’t resolved the contradiction of him saying he was forsaken. Why did he say it then?

Comment: I did explain the why in the first four paragraphs of my post. David said the words at Psalm 22:1, why did he say them? Why did Jesus quote the words? Again, David was being hunted down by King Saul. At vs2 he says, "I cry by day, but Thou does not answer, and by night I have no rest." Jesus is a 100% contingent human being which means He depended on God at all times just like Christians are suppose to do. Jesus had no rest as well when He prayed in the Garden and sweated drops of blood before His crucifixion. Both Jesus and David FELT forsaken, they were not. Read Psalm 22: 24-27.

Comment: You still don't get it. Why did Jesus say the words if he was not forsaken? IOW, WHY is he quoting Ps 22 then? **Why Jesus said that the God abandoned Him?** you haven't answered yet.

Comment: @steveowen Oh I get it alright. Let me put it to you this way with a question? It was David who said, "My God my God why hast Thou forsaken me? Far from My deliverance are the words of my groaning." Those are David's explicit words. Did God forsake David or abandon him?

Comment: @steveowen Still waiting for you to address a simple question I asked you. ". Did God forsake David or abandon him?" And by the way, I plan on addressing the following statement of yours on another thread where you said, "Jesus Christ became flesh at John 1:14 is a lie!"

Comment: the Q is not about David.  Does Jesus make the connection to David or is it just you? And good, I'll anticipate more obfuscation and interchanging words to suit your dogma and using obscure ideas to deny what scripture plainly says. But yes, we know God does not forsake, but you are yet to explain *why Jesus said it*. Are you not able to put it succinctly.

Comment: He said it to fulfill prophecy. Another excellent example is at Luke 4:18-21. "The Spirit of the Lord is upon Me, Because He anointed Me to preach the gospel to the poor. He has sent Me to proclaim release to the captives, and recovery of sight to the blind, To set free those are downtrodden, To proclaim the favorable year of the Lord." At vs21, "And He began to say to them, "Today this Scripture has been fulfilled in your hearing." Jesus is quoting Isaiah 61:1-2. Notice Jesus did not quote the following words of the prophecy. "And the day of vengeance of our God; To comfort all who mourn."